# Usos de las funciones SQL delcarados en un SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas tardes a tod@s.

Tengo una pregunta que quizá sea una idea descabellada pero que realmente me frena muchas consultas por mi poca experiencia en SQL Server.

¿Podría utilizar una función declarada en un `SELECT` con su alias y utilizar dicho alias para filtrar algún mando en `WHERE` ?

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(P.PlatoId) AS [PlatosTotales]
FROM dbo.Platos P
WHERE PlatosTotales > 10
```

Se podría de alguna manera hacer algo así ?

Muchas gracias por su atención.

Un cordial saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola creo que este ejemplo puede ayudarte :

```
SELECT COUNT( a.shipmentDocumentID) AS 'documentos' FROM tblShipmentDocuments a having  COUNT(a.shipmentDocumentID)> 10
```

cuando haces **select** usando **count**  en vez de utilizar **where** debe utilizar el **having** para filtrar datos en funcion a dicha agregación.

Answer (score 2):

Los resultados de las funciones de agregación no se pueden usar con `WHERE` debido a que

- `WHERE` trabaja sobre columnas de valores existentes
- Tu cálculo se genera al momento de la consulta por lo cual antes no existe

Debería ser más simple la consulta usando `HAVING` que si te puede filtrar por el resultado de `COUNT` así

```
SELECT
    COUNT(P.PlatoId) AS [PlatosTotales]
FROM dbo.Platos P
HAVING PlatosTotales > 10
```

Entonces dado el contexto de la misma pregunta:

- No es necesario escribir el cuerpo de una función, cuando el propio motor ya dispone de las herramientas para ello
- Por cierto, verifica el uso de corchetes al invocar el alias pues yo no uso SQL Server por lo tanto ese detalle se me escapa

Answer (score 2):

Exactamente como lo planteas, no, dado que la columna por la que estás consultando es una columna creada por el select y no existente dentro de la tabla. Sin embargo para lo que quieres ejemplificar podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(P.PlatoId) AS [PlatosTotales]
FROM dbo.Platos P
HAVING COUNT(P.PlatoId)> 10
```

[HAVING](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) no acepta los alias en su búsqueda ya que esta es evaluada antes del SELECT.